# How to update the details of the user in Firebase Authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to develop an app in android studio using firebase where user verifies their email address after signup. But even after verifying the email address, whenever I open the app again, it forwards me to the send email verification code page. However, if I clear app data, the same problem does not exist.

I tried using AuthStateListener (without knowing much about it) but it did not work.

here is the code that I tried. I also tried it without the authstatelistener, but the same problem continued

```
   mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    authStateListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
                startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this,VerifyEmail.class));
            }
        }
    };
```

It leads to the verify email page if I open it in the phone where I signed up. But after clearing the data, it does not forward me to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue is the FirebaseUser object is cached in the app by default. That's why there is no problem when the app data is cleared. To fix this call `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().reload()` when your app starts.

```
mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
user.reload()
if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
     startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this,VerifyEmail.class));
}
```